# configurable FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY (retrieve 1, n, or all rows)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to make a select statement retrieves **ALL** the rows when the clause `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` is used?

say I have the function:

```
function fill_ids_array(n in number default 1) is
begin
  select id
    into t_ids_array
    from some_table
   fetch first n rows only;
end;
```

How to make this function fill **all** ids into the array variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly like that.

```
SQL> create or replace function fill_ids_array(n in number default 1)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_tab sys.odcinumberlist;
  5  begin
  6    select empno
  7      bulk collect into l_tab
  8      from emp
  9      fetch first n rows only;
 10
 11    return l_tab.count;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select fill_ids_array(6) cnt from dual;

       CNT
----------
         6

SQL> select fill_ids_array(3) cnt from dual;

       CNT
----------
         3

SQL> select fill_ids_array cnt from dual;

       CNT
----------
         1

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, based on Jon's comment]**

If parameter's default value is set to `binary_float_infinity`, then - if you don't pass *any* parameter, you'll fetch all rows; otherwise, fetch as many rows as parameter value says:

```
SQL> create or replace function fill_ids_array(n in number default binary_float_infinity)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_tab sys.odcinumberlist;
  5  begin
  6    select empno
  7      bulk collect into l_tab
  8      from emp
  9      fetch first n rows only;
 10
 11    return l_tab.count;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select fill_ids_array result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
        14

SQL> select fill_ids_array(3) result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also need the function to retrieve all empno values not only a specific first n value.

Comment: Sorry, but - that doesn't make sense. If you want to retrieve **all** values, then remove FETCH clause entirely.

Comment: @Littlefoot - I think the OP wants to use a simple numeric parameter, and they probably want to avoid using a dynamic query or multiple queries like in MTO's answer. I think your code would match the OP's requirements if you change the parameter default to `DEFAULT BINARY_FLOAT_INFINITY`.

Comment: Thank you, @Jon. That might be the case; I added some more code that illustrates it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `IF` statement to handle the case when you want all rows:

```sql
FUNCTION fill_ids_array(
  n in number default 1
) RETURN number_list
IS
  t_ids_array number_list;
BEGIN
  IF n IS NULL THEN
    -- All rows
    SELECT id
    BULK COLLECT INTO t_ids_array
    FROM   some_table;
  ELSE
    -- Specified number of rows
    SELECT id
    BULK COLLECT INTO t_ids_array
    FROM   some_table
    FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY;
  END IF;

  RETURN t_ids_array;
END;
```

If you want to make it explicit that you want all the rows then you can use:

```sql
FETCH FIRST 100 PERCENT ROWS ONLY
```